# how to insert some variables into an html by attaching it the var at the end of html page

Tags: javascript, html

I am using a microcontroller and I'm communicating with it via a html page.

The pages are stored as some constant in the microcontroller and are sent to PC for display purposes.

I want to attach my variable data at the end of html page that is sent into the PC to display  them in the boxes that are in the middle of the page.

Before that I was forced to find the exact position of variable in the html in the box .

Is there any way to show the data that is attached at the end of the html in the middle boxes of the page?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>SAAT Co</title>
<h1><center><font color="red"> SAAT Co </font></center></h1>\r\n<h1><fontcolor="blue">   Ethernet Display T24M08 </font></h1>\r\n
<script>
<--
function validateForm()
{
var x=document.forms["myForm"]["fname"].value;
if (x==null || x=="")
  {
  alert("First name must be filled out");
  return false;
  }
}
-->
</script>
</head>

<body>

   <form name="myForm" action="http://192.168.1.250" onsubmit="return validateForm()" method="post">
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>Firmware Version :</td>
    <td><input type="text" name="dev-info" value=" " ></td>

  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>MAC Adress :</td>
    <td><input type="text" name="mac-addr"></td>

  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>IP Adress :</td>
    <td><input type="text" name="ip-addr"></td>

  </tr>
</table>
<input type="submit" value="Apply/Reboot">
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Dude, we haven't needed to use HTML comments to hide JavaScript <!-- --> since 1996. Where did you get this antique code?

Comment: where r u reading the data from?And where is that portion in the html above?

Comment: @Diodeus - You just *think* that's a comment. Bwahaha `<font>`.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand you correctly, you can accomplish what you're trying to do by assigning your values to their appropriate textboxes.  The example below does this by giving your textbox an ID and then using javascript to insert your value into that textbox.

```
      <td>MAC Adress :</td>
      <td><input type="text" id='MacAddy' name="mac-addr"></td>
      ...
      </form>
   </body>
</html>

<script>
    document.getElementById('MacAddy').value = "your_value_here";
</script>
```

The javascript can be appended to the document in the fashion you described in your post.